# Relational Database - How to decide whether to store data or calculate data?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Let's say you have two tables in a database, one for golf players and one for golf holes, along with an API that has to return something like total fairways that player has hit in his/her life. Is it best practice to have the API look at every hole to calculate the number for fairways hit, or just store fairways hit directly in the players table? It seems as though storing this data in the players table is basically duplicating the data, as it already lives in each hole. But in order to calculate it, you need to go through every hole that player has played, every time.

More generally, is this simply a situation where you need to balance correct data design with performance?

I realize this may require a subjective answer (sorry if it does), but I don't know enough about database design to know if their is a definitive answer to situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> More generally, is this simply a situation where you need to balance correct data design with performance?

TL;DR "Yes".

The relational model has nothing to do with performance. The *relational model of data* is a formal theory; it's one of many data models.

> A **data model** is an abstract, self-contained, logical definition of
>   the objects, operators, and so forth, that together constitute the
>   *abstract machine* with which users interact.[1]

An abstract machine has no performance problems, because it doesn't exist in a physical sense. That's why, for example, the relational model says nothing about indexes.

On the other hand, a SQL database has a *lot* do do with performance. A SQL database has a physical implementation whose performance is affected by the number of cores; amount of memory; disk space, configuration, and spindle speed; number of concurrent users; indexes; and so on.

The difference is the difference between logical and physical, between abstract and concrete, and between principle and practice.

So yes, you need to balance clean design with performance. Everybody does.

The best way to do that is to "do a clean logical (i.e. relational) design first, and then, as a separate and subsequent step, to map that logical design into whatever physical structures the target DMBS happens to support."[2]

If you have to store the result of calculations, best practice is to make the SQL DBMS maintain consistency. For example, if you have to store the result of `(quantity * price) + sales_tax`, write a CHECK() constraint to guarantee consistency. Some DBMS don't support CHECK() constraints.

If you have to maintain tallys (counts) across many rows, use a materialized view. Some DBMS don't support materialized views.

In the worst case, you can only use a report that a person reads to determine whether an inconsistency has crept in. The person takes corrective action.

In all cases, measure performance of representative INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements before and after making changes.

> Is it best practice to have the API look at every hole to calculate the number for fairways hit, or just store fairways hit directly in the players table?

There are many statistics. You should *probably* store statistics in one or more additional tables. SQL DBMS don't have to "look at every hole"; they operate on sets.

> But in order to calculate it, you need to go through every hole that player has played, every time.

No, you don't need to "go through every hole", at least not in the sense of *iterating* through every hole, although that's exactly what a lot of front-end application frameworks do. You just need a single SQL query like `select count(*) from player_holes where fairway_hit = True;`.

---

[1] *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, C. J. Date, p 14

[2] ibid, p 327.

Comment: You reminded me of something I read recently: "The aim of the System R project was to refute the claims of those pundits who asserted that Codd’s Model was infeasible, for performance reasons. SQL was designed by people whose primary interests and skills lay in DBMS engineering [rather than] computer language design." [source](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html)

Comment: "Some DBMS don't support CHECK() constraints" - those that do tend to restrict them to attribute level an tuple level due to the complexities of relation and database constraints of arbitrary complexity. MS Access supposedly supports table-level check constraints but they actually get checked on row-by-row basis, making them practically useless!

Answer (score 3):

Storing derived data creates certain risks or responsibilities. You have to maintain the derived data or risk wrong answers. This can add complexity and workload to a system. In some cases, it's worth it to add complexity at write time in order to reduce it at read time, especially if the calculation is complex and the calculated results can be updated incrementally.

In your example, I would try to achieve good performance via indexing before storing derived data. It sounds like a query that can be answered from a suitable index alone, without loading any physical rows.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with denormalisation is the serialisation and complexity of code required to maintain the duplicate data.

I don't think that you have that problem here, because you are maintaining an historical data set that is not going to change -- or at least, only very rarely.

I don't believe that there would be harm in providing summaries of the detailed statistics, and maintaining them as the data changes. An Oracle materialized view would manage this for you, although it is not a cheap option.